# The code is pushed to the main thread, how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

This code works even when I exit the activity and go to another activity. In order to understand this, I went to another activity and deleted the path in Firebase and the application crashed due to the fact that this path no longer exists. I would like to disable this code when I exit the activity, how can I do this?

```
private void addRoomEventListener() {
        messageRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (role.equals("host:")) {
                    if (snapshot.getValue(String.class).contains("guest:")) {
                        step.setEnabled(true);
                        Toast.makeText(DuelGame.this, "" +
                                snapshot.getValue(String.class).replace("guest:", ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (snapshot.getValue(String.class).contains("host:")) {
                        step.setEnabled(true);
                        Toast.makeText(DuelGame.this, "" +
                                snapshot.getValue(String.class).replace("host:", ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                messageRef.setValue(message);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save `addValueEventLister` call in a variable `yourListener` and then do this when switching to another activity or when the current activity is going to finish ( usually in `onPause()` or `onStop()`),

```
dbref.removeEventListener(yourListener);
```

Comment: What should I put under "your Listener"? `messageRef`?

Comment: No, you have to save the entire addValueEventListener in a variable and pass that variable to removeEventListener

Comment: I already figured it out, thanks